How to create User class to deal with flask-form and pymysql
I'm trying to build a flask app, normally I use SQ lite with sqlalchemy, but i use flask-login to handle all the login
now I m switching to using MySQL and for the database connecter I choose to use pymysql
my problem comes when i need to use the flask-login
in my current app to handle the user, i build a base SQL
db_connect.py
import pymysql
from my_app import app

def create_db():
    db = pymysql.connect(host=app.config['MYSQL_HOST'],
                         user=app.config['MYSQL_USER'],
                         passwd=app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
                         db=app.config['MYSQL_DB'],
                         port=app.config['MYSQL_PORT'])
    try:
        print("Creating database...")
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    user_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                    joined_at DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE),
                    last_update DATETIME DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW())
                    ''')
        db.commit()
        cur.close()
        print("Database created")
        app.logger.info('Database created')
        db.close()
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print(f'Error while creating table: {e.args[0]}, {e.args[1]}')
        app.logger.error(e)





class MySqlBase:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, db, port):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db = db
        self.port=port

    def __connection(self):
        try:
            return pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, passwd=self.password, db=self.db, port=self.port)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print(f"Error while opening sql connection: {str(e)}")

    def execute(self, sql: str, args: list=None): 
        with self.__connection() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(sql, args)
                connection.commit()
                return cursor


    def execute_many(self, sql: str, args: list[tuple]=None):
        with self.__connection() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.executemany(sql, args)
                connection.commit()
                return cursor

    def select(self, sql: str, args: list = None):
        cursor = self.execute(sql, args)
        return cursor.fetchall()

    def select_many(self, sql: str, args: list[tuple]=None):
        cursor = self.execute(sql, args)
        return cursor.fetchall()

now for the user repository class
user.py
from my_app import app
from my_app.db_connect import MySqlBase



class UserRepository(MySqlBase):
    def __init__(self):
        MySqlBase.__init__(self, app.config['MYSQL_HOST'],
                         app.config['MYSQL_USER'],
                         app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
                         app.config['MYSQL_DB'],
                         app.config['MYSQL_PORT'])


    def get(self, id):
        query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %s'
        return self.select(query, [id])

    def get_all(self):
        query = 'SELECT * FROM users'
        return self.select(query)

    def insert(self, user_name, address, email, password):
        query = 'INSERT INTO users(user_name, address, email, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)'
        return self.execute(query, [user_name, address, email, password])


    def update(self, id, user_name, address, email, password):
        query = 'UPDATE users SET user_name = %s, address = %s, email = %s, password = %s WHERE id = %s'
        return self.execute(query, [user_name, address, email, password, id])

    def delete(self, id):
        query = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE id = %s'
        return self.execute(query, [id])

now for the login,
i dont want to use sqlalchemy, shall i build a User class to use it with flask-login or query the database directly using my UserRepository or not use flask-login at all and use session ?
Thank you in advance
I try to use session only without flask-login, it works fine but I have to build all the functions manual
normally with sqlalchemy we built user class like this
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


As an aside, your MySqlBase class is poorly designed. The expectation is that when you use a database connection or cursor as a context manager, (e.g. with self.__connection() as connection:, when you exit this block, which occurs when method execute returns, both the connection and cursor are expected to be closed automatically. Therefore the subsequent call cursor.fetchall() made in method select should not work. It appears you code only works because pymysql is not implementing as expected, i.e. not closing connections and cursors. (more...)

If you were to switch to using MySQLdb for example, which would require minimal changes, your code would stop working. Also, you are creating a new connection for each call to select, which is horribly inefficient and these connections will only be closed when garbage collected.

@Booboo thank you for the great advice, i redesign the base class
i made the excute  __execute and i added simple execute that return self.__execute(sql, args)
i also deleted the __execute many
please feel free to suggest any changes
thank you
